# Use of undeclared identifier in embedded framework

Tags: ios

I am trying to move all the common files from my project to an embedded framework which I can use in my Today Extension. When I try to add the .framework to my target from Build Phases, the framework appears for a second and disappears and doesn't let me add it to the target. How do I fix this?

Here are errors which arise

[image: Build Errors]

Comment: Please check if you have created framework correctly.

Comment: I created new target for framework with a different name, changed all the file memberships to the new framework, added all Headers as Public Headers, the framework appeared in my app target's build phase->Link Binary with Libraries but these errors still appear

Comment: Do your imports have the framework name? <UWCFramework/UWCClient>

Comment: I seemed to have solved this issue, don't remember how